# 2nd order coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

Working on a mechanical problem I obtain a system of two coupled differential equations (Eq.1 and Eq.2) in **r** and **theta** using polar coordinates system.

I have summarized everything on the figure attached with this post and I hope that it is quite explicit. Would you have informations on the numerical method to be used to solve such a system (using Scilab or Matlab or whatever).

Many thanks to all.

[image]

Comment: Are you meaning $m(\theta)=a(1-|\cos\theta|)+b$? And are $r$ and $\theta$ functions of $t$?

Comment: Totally, sorry for the notations. Moreover there is a little wording mistake in Eq.1. It is **r** and not **p** at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

First I post the equations system (I corrected 2 mistakes).

[image]

Now, I propose a Scilab code (equivalent to Matlab) to solve it by creating a first order system of differential equations.

> ```
> t0 =  0; // initial time (s)
> tmax = 30; // solving max time (s)
> tinc = 0.005; // time increment (s)
>
> t = t0:tinc:tmax;
>
> // Differential equations system
>
> function du = equadiff(t,u)
>
>   // d for derivative with respect to time t
>   // u(1) = theta
>   // u(2) = d(theta)/dt
>   // u(3) = r
>   // u(4) = d(r)/dt
>   // du(1) = d(theta)/dt
>   // du(2) = d²(theta)dt²
>   // du(3) = d(r)/dt
>   // du(4) = d²(r)/dt²
>
>   F1=1300;
>   F2=1000;
>   l=13;
>   k=68000;
>   menv = 112.14;
>   m0 = 56.07;
>   g=9.81;
>
>   m = (menv - m0) * (1-abs(cos(u(1)))) + m0;
>   du(1) = u(2);
>   du(2) = (F2*sin(u(1)) + (F1-m*g).*cos(u(1)) - 2*m.*u(4).*u(2)) ./ (m.*u(3));
>   du(3) = u(4);
>   du(4) = ((F1-m*g).*sin(u(1)) - F2*cos(u(1)) - k*(u(3)-l) + m.*u(3).*u(2).*u(2)) ./ m;
>
> endfunction
>
> // Integration
>
> u0 = [0,0,13,0]';
> [u] = ode(u0,t0,t,equadiff);
>
> // Plot theta for example
> plot(t,u(1,:));
> ```